# c++ regex in loop

Tags: c++, regex

The following attempts to get the "a" from "A:a" and "b" from "B:b" and "c" from "C:c" by performing a regex search in a loop. In the first iteration of the outer loop, "a" appears in the second group of m. However for the second iteration of the outer loop, "b" appears in the third group of m. And for the third iteration of the outer loop, "c" appears in the fourth group of m. Why is that? Also, the first iteration of the outer loop has 4 groups in m. Why is that? Shouldn't there be two groups?

```
std::string s = "abc\n"
    "A:a\n"
    "def\n"
    "B:b\n"
    "ghi\n"
    "C:c\n\n"
    "jkl\n";
std::regex p("\nA:\\s*([^\n]+)|\nB:\\s*([^\n]+)|\nC:\\s*([^\n]+)");
std::smatch m;

while (std::regex_search(s, m, p))
{
    int count = 0;
    for (auto x:m)
    {
        std::cout << count << "->" << x << ", ";
        count++;
    }
    s = m.suffix().str();
}
```

The output is

```
0->
A:a, 1->a, 2->, 3->, 0->
B:b, 1->, 2->b, 3->, 0->
C:c, 1->, 2->, 3->c,
```

Expected:

```
0->
A:a, 1->a, 0->
B:b, 1->b, 0->
C:c, 1->c,
```

Comment: It looks correct to me. Your regex has 3 defined groups. First of these groups catches whatever is after `A:` and any number of whitespace. Second group would catch anything after `B:` and whitespaces. Third group catches anything after `C:` and whitespaces. What did you expect?

Comment: I've added the expected output above.

Comment: If the group was not used in match, it doesn't mean that this group doesn't exist. It's just empty. I always assumed that this is how regular expression languages works, but I'm not sure about that.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen That's correct. Group numbers simply count `(` from the left. The group number doesn't reset in each alternative.

Comment: Thanks. I thought the numbering starts at the index of the substring matched by group(0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group numbers don't reset in each alternative.

Since all your alternatives are the same except for the letter at the beginning, you can simply combine them into a single alternative and match the letter with `[ABC]`.

```
std::regex p("\n[ABC]:\\s*([^\n]+)");
```